# To disable drive access and allow access only from remote system

Tags: authentication, remote-access, windows, drive

I have around 5 system in my network. All are windows 7 Professional and are connect through LAN. I can access all drives from one system to another. However, i want that some particular drives of systems can just only be accessed by 1 PC.

To be more precise: Let say we have 5 systems `SYS1` `SYS2` `SYS3` `SYS4` `SYS5` and in all systems I have created drive with letter "`Z:`". Now what i want that only `SYS1` can access drive `Z:` of all systems and others can't.

So is it possible with the basic computing knowledge. If yes then how?

And if not possible is there any alternate method which i can use to achieve my objective, like any software...

Comment: Why a down vote, i think i have a justified question and its not already available there in serverfault?

Comment: Not my downvote (I usually explain why I down vote), but I suspect it is because your question strongly smells of a home user setup. In a office I would expect a domain and a file-server. And no data on local PCs without a damn good reason.

Comment: @Hennes Yes it is a home setup, and i was just thinking to implement it.... just for knowledge... was this wrong?

Comment: @AbhilashShukla It's not wrong to experiment, but ServerFault is specially "reserved" for questions of a professional nature. Check out our [FAQ]

Comment: @Dan Ok, was not aware, sorry... will take care from next time and will surely explore faq's before posting from next time :)

Answer (score 1):

You can share a drive or folder and protect it with a password.

Thus on `SYS2`, `SYS3`,`SYS4` and `SYS5` go to the drive, right click, share with, advanced sharing. Add a share and make sure you set the permissions to only allow the right user or computer to access them.

This really should have been part of your professional IT education, both in general and when you learned about active directory and domains.  (Hint: Posters on ServerFault are supposed to know this. Check our FAQ. Also check-out our sister site Superuser).

Comment: ohkey~ got that... lemme check and thanks for insight